# assigning a signal to a non parent module

Tags: chisel

I know that in Verilog if you want to propagate a signal you have to add the signal to the ports of the module and propagate it across all the modules until you are able to connect it. I suspect that is the same for chisel but as I'm a novice...

Is it possible to connect a signal of a submodule directly to a port on a higher level module?

For instance:

Module hierarchy

top->my_peripheral->the_counter_inside_peripheral->output_my_signal
top->another_peripheral->input_process_signals

```
my_peripheral.the_counter_inside_peripheral.output_my_signal := another_peripheral.input_process_signals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chisel is the same as Verilog in this regard. In the next major version release (3.2) we will have experimental support for such synthesizable cross-module connections, but it's not yet in the published versions.

If you build from source, you can try this out sooner by taking a look at the [BoringUtils](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/b3bd3c430d39e344dc6224717efeca26c9c91378/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/experimental/BoringUtils.scala#L111).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.